# Is setRetainInstance is supported with FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to retain the instance of an object on configuration changes using Fragments. And I want to support older versions of android using support library. So I extended FragmentActivity like this.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class test extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle state){
        super.onCreate(state);  
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }
}
```

But when I do this, Eclips complains that there is no such a thing as setRetainInstance. But when I change the FragmentActivity to Fragment every thing is OK.
what am I missing?

Comment: Maintain that object in your one of `Fragment` class...

Comment: But Fragment class is not available in below API 13. How to deal with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setRetainInstance(Boolean)` is a method in `Fragment` class. not of `FragmentActivity` class...

and There is a support library for `Fragment`s in Android SDK.

see at `android-sdk/extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar`